# Rapidjson still aborts even though RAPIDJSON_ASSERT has been re-defined

Tags: c++, abort, rapidjson

I modified the definition of RAPIDJSON_ASSERT in rapidjson.h to:

```
#define RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(x) (if(!(x)) throw std::logic_error("Rapidjson assertion error") )
```

but still the program aborts in document.h line 1103. Does anyone know why? thank you.

```
template <typename SourceAllocator>
GenericValue& operator[](const GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>& name) {
    MemberIterator member = FindMember(name);
    if (member != MemberEnd())
        return member->value;
    else {
        RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(false);    // line 1103. see above note

        // This will generate -Wexit-time-destructors in clang
        // static GenericValue NullValue;
        // return NullValue;

        // Use static buffer and placement-new to prevent destruction
        static char buffer[sizeof(GenericValue)];
        return *new (buffer) GenericValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against using images of code. Images are hard to search, opaque to the visually impaired, blocked by firewalls, brutally hard to compile, and big and bulky compared to displaying text as text. You should only use images as supplemental information or if the question is about the image, for example, "Why am I getting this distortion pattern?"

Comment: Did you define it before including any RapidJSON headers?

Comment: @MiloYip, after, but it shouldn't matter right? Rapidson is header-only library.

Comment: @i_love_rain Since it is a header-only library, you need to define the macros before including the headers. Otherwise, it won't be in effect. A better option will be using -DRAPIDJSON_ASSERT=... as a compilation option.